# How to compare a value with three other values and take decision

Tags: jquery

I have got a stock price value and three suppourt values for it. I am trying to check if Stock Current Price is less than of greater than of `-3`, then print yes or else no. This is my code

```
var price = parseFloat(1645.70) ;

var suppourt1 = parseFloat(1649.32);
var suppourt2 = parseFloat(1604.40);
var suppourt3 = parseFloat(1559.36);
var diff = price - suppourt1;

if (diff >= -3 && diff <= 3) {
  alert('yes');
} else {
  alert('No');
}
```

Here I am checking only for `suppourt1`. How do I need to check for `suppourt2` as well as `suppourt3`?

Do I need to add 3 more `if` to achieve this?

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/470/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need three separate `if` statements, but you will at least need three conditions within a single `if` statement to check all the differences.

Note however that you can make the logic simpler - assuming that the difference you're trying to measure will be from `-X` to `+X` - by getting the absolute value. That way you only need to check `<=`. Try this:

```js
var price = parseFloat(1645.70);
var maxDelta = 3;

var suppourt1 = parseFloat(1649.32);
var suppourt2 = parseFloat(1604.40);
var suppourt3 = parseFloat(1559.36);
var diff1 = Math.abs(price - suppourt1);
var diff2 = Math.abs(price - suppourt2);
var diff3 = Math.abs(price - suppourt3);

if (diff1 <= maxDelta && diff2 <= maxDelta && diff3 <= maxDelta) {
    console.log('yes');
} else {
    console.log('No');
}
```

Finally, the use of `parseFloat()` is redundant as you're providing literal values, although I presume this is just due to the way you've transcribed your question.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend storing the three variables in an array.

```
array = [value1, value2, value3];
```

And then looping through it and do IFs:

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i] >=-3 && array[i] <=3) {
    alert('yes');
  } else {
    alert('No');
  }
}
```

So the whole code could look like this:

```
var price = parseFloat(1645.70) ;
var supportsArray = [1649.32, 1604.40, 1559.36];
var diff;

for (i = 0; i < supportsArray.length; i++) {
   diff = price - supportsArray[i];

   if (diff >=- 3 && diff <= 3) {
        alert('yes');
      } else {
        alert('No');
   }
}
```